# Save Data Between pages in asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I'm Creating an asp.net Web Site using C#.

I have a page called Set Event which has some text fields. After filling some of them there is a button that redirects the user to another page. This page has a button that will do some database process and then redirects to the previous page.

After that page processes I want to redirect back to the previous page (Set Event) to fill other text fields.

The question is: when I redirect to the previous page my previous filled data is gone--empty text boxes.  Where has my data gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options (IMO)

1. Keep passing the data back and forth from client to server, i.e. hidden fields, viewstate, etc.
2. save the data in Session, i.e. Session["field1"] = "field1data", or a database, cache, etc.

then recall it on the original page.

Comment: They have to be saved some where in order to recall it or you will lose the data.

Comment: Thanks sir... I make  that using Session object... i make dataset from all data in text fields and after i restore that... this realy helped me lot...

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect it is a new HTTP request. HTTP is stateless. so it wont keep the data you entered earlier there. You should read it from a persistant storage mecahnism and load that to the textboxes. Since you are saving that to the database. You can read that from the database tables and load it there.